# Eager-Loading related entities

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate for ORM, I have there entities User, Person and address with OnetoOne relationship I use Eager fetchType. Address is related to Person and Person is related to User. when I output from jsp I only get the values from User and others are null.

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User1")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int id;

@Column(name = "Username",length = 50)
private String username;

@Column(name = "Email",length = 50)
private String email;

@Column(name = "ContactNO" ,length = 50)
private String contact_no;

@Column(name = "Password", length = 50)
private String password;

@Transient
private boolean canEdit;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Person person;
```

Person

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int person_id;

@Column(name = "Name", length = 50)
private String name;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Address address;

@Transient
private boolean canEdit;
```

Address

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Address")
public class Address {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int add_id;

@Column(name ="Street" ,length = 50)
private String street;

@Column(name = "City" ,length = 50)
private String city;

@Column(name = "PostalCode" ,length = 50)
private String postalCode;

@Column(name = "Country" ,length = 50)
private String country;

@Transient
private boolean canEdit;
```

Comment: How do you output it to JSP?

Comment: <p:column>
                        <f:facet name = "header">Name</f:facet> 
                        <p:inputText size = "10" value = "#{user.person.name}" rendered = "#{user.canEdit}" /> 
                        <p:inputText size = "20" value = "#{usermbean.user.person.name}"  rendered = "#{usermbean.user.person.canEdit}" /> 
                        <h:outputText value = "#{user.person.name}" rendered = "#{not user.canEdit}" />
                    </p:column>

Answer (score 0):

To map the relation between tables, you should indicate what column should be connected between 2 tables. You can do it by using MappedBy property put in OneToOne anotation.

Can you try to you this:

**User Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User1")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int id;

@Column(name = "Username",length = 50)
private String username;

@Column(name = "Email",length = 50)
private String email;

@Column(name = "ContactNO" ,length = 50)
private String contact_no;

@Column(name = "Password", length = 50)
private String password;

@Transient
private boolean canEdit;

// add mappedBy to indicate person in table Person
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Person person;
```

**Person Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int person_id;

@Column(name = "Name", length = 50)
private String name;

// For OneToOne relation between User-Person
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "id") // assume you express this relation by adding user's id to Person
private User user; 

// add mappedBy to indicate person in table Address
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Address address;

@Transient
private boolean canEdit;
```

**Address Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Address")
public class Address {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int add_id;

@Column(name ="Street" ,length = 50)
private String street;

@Column(name = "City" ,length = 50)
private String city;

@Column(name = "PostalCode" ,length = 50)
private String postalCode;

@Column(name = "Country" ,length = 50)
private String country;

// For OneToOne relation between Person-Address
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id") // assume you express this relation by adding person's id to Address
private Person person;

@Transient
private boolean canEdit;
```

Also, you can find more detail [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html)